# Codemirror changing TEXT color with Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, codemirror

I'm trying to use Codemirror with Angular 4/2 to simply change the color of a certain word inside the  tags (see the app.component.html). I was able to implement Codemirror in Angular 4 and setup some simple configuration, but the documentation does not explain how to do more complex configuration in Angular 4 (like changing the color of a word).
My code:

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Codemirror</title>
  <base href="/">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://npmcdn.com/codemirror@5.24.0/lib/codemirror.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CodemirrorModule } from 'ng2-codemirror';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    CodemirrorModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import 'codemirror';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  config;
  content;
  constructor() {
    this.config = {
      lineNumbers: true,
      mode: 'text/typescript'
    };
    this.content = 'merkel AND trump';
  }

  oninput() {
    console.log('blabla');
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<h1>Codemirror sample with Angular 2</h1>
<div style="border: 1px solid black">
  <codemirror [(ngModel)]="content" [config]="config" (input)="oninput()"></codemirror>
</div>
```

As you can see, the initial string is "merkel AND trump" (for tests purpose). How would I configure Codemirror in angular 4 to change the color of each word "AND" ? I've no idea how to proceed for using it with typescript angular 4, so I'd appreciate any help.

Best regards,

Marcos

Comment: just to update, I was able to acchieve it by using pure Javascript.

Comment: <textarea rows="4" cols="30" id="cm" name="cm">merkel AND trump</textarea>

Comment: CodeMirror.defineMode("customMode", function() {
    
    return {
        token: function(stream,state) {
            
            if (stream.match("AND") ) {
                return "redstyle";
            } else if (stream.match("OR") ) {
                return "redstyle";
            } else if (stream.match("NOT") ) {
                return "redstyle";
            } else {stream.next();
                return null;}
        }
    };
    
});
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('cm'), {
    mode: "customMode",
    lineNumbers: true
});

Comment: .cm-redstyle { color: red; }

Comment: but like I said, in ANGULAR 4 is the goal and so far I've not succeded